# Trying (and failing) to build OCaml package "Javalib"

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, package-managers, opam

I'm trying to build the OCaml package Javalib through opam. I can't get it to build, here is the ouput:

```
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install javalib 2.3.1

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[javalib] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[ERROR] The compilation of javalib failed at "make".
Processing  1/1: [javalib: ocamlfind remove]
#=== ERROR while installing javalib.2.3.1 =====================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           linux
# command      make
# path         /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/javalib.2.3.1
# compiler     system (4.02.3)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/javalib.2.3.1/javalib-1074-d2c37b.env
# stdout-file  /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/javalib.2.3.1/javalib-1074-d2c37b.out
# stderr-file  /home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/javalib.2.3.1/javalib-1074-d2c37b.err
### stdout ###
# [...]
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jDumpBasics.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jParseCode.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jInstruction.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jUnparseSignature.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jDumpLow.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jHigh2Low.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jDumpJasmin.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -c jUnparse.ml
# /home/mttjone/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlc -g -w Aer -annot -package unix,str,extlib,ptrees,zip -package camlp4 -syntax camlp4o -c jParseSignature.ml
# make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/home/mttjone/.opam/system/build/javalib.2.3.1/src'
### stderr ###
# [...]
# Warning 44: this open statement shadows the value identifier write_ui16 (which is later used)
# File "jUnparse.ml", line 22, characters 0-17:
# Warning 44: this open statement shadows the value identifier write_i32 (which is later used)
# sh: camlp4: command not found
# File "jParseSignature.ml", line 1:
# Error: Error while running external preprocessor
# Command line: camlp4 '-I' '/home/mttjone/sw//lib/ocaml/camlp4' '-parser' 'o' '-parser' 'op' '-printer' 'p'  'jParseSignature.ml' > /tmp/ocamlpp214326
#
# make[1]: *** [jParseSignature.cmo] Error 2
# make: *** [javalib] Error 2



=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The following actions failed
  ∗  install javalib 2.3.1
No changes have been performed
```

I first thought that I was missing camlp4, but I'm not. Interestingly though it doesn't reside in the lib/ocaml directory.

It could have something to do with the `jUnparse.ml` or `jParseSignature.ml` files, but I don't really know OCaml, and can't quite parse what's happening in them.

Comment: looks like that you forgot to activate `opam`. Use `eval $(opam config env)` command before installing the package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I could install half a dozen packages before this became an issue. Anyways, I ran `opam switch 4.02.3` then `eval \`opam config env\`` and now it works.

Comment: yep, many packages do not rely on the environment that hard. I would say that it may be a considered a bug of `javalib`, since it is possible to install without an activated environment. But, we don't have such policy, so package maintainers can actually rely on the environment.

Comment: @Jones had the same problem and your solution works.